# Phrase or way to say 'thought should be given'

Tags: phrases, expressions

Is there a better way to say 'thought should be given'?

For example:

> *Thought should be given as to how to decrease the deficit.*

What is a better way to say that?

Comment: If you don't like 'thought', then you could use "*Attention* should be given..." If you want to be a bit more forceful, I'd rewrite to something like  "Strategies for deficit reduction should be examined." (or 'considered', or 'addressed' etc)

Answer (score 1):

To think about something or give it some thought is akin to **pondering**.

**ponder**:

> think about (something) carefully, especially before making a
>   decision or reaching a conclusion.

Hence, you can look at the following alternatives:

> 1. **consider** as to how to decrease the deficit
> 2. **ponder** on how to decrease the deficit
> 3. **study** as to how to decrease the deficit

Answer (score 1):

*I think we should **mull** over how to decrease the deficit.*

> mull (over): to think about carefully; consider. ([**RH**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mull--over))

Answer (score 0):

1. **Strategic vision**(=idea) is needed to control the deficit.
2. We must have **strategic planning** to reduce the deficit.

Answer (score 0):

We need to **put our heads together** to find ways to decrease the deficits. This is probably the most colloquial way to say something like that.

*According to TheFreeDictionary:*

> Definition: if a group of people put their heads together, they think
>   about something in order to get ideas or to solve a problem

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+heads+together